# Syntax Error ruby on rails unexpected ':', expecting '}' when calling render json:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts

Error:

```
SyntaxError in UsersController#index
 /home/ubuntu/ruby/users/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
      format.json{render json: UsersDatatable.new(view_context)}
                              ^
```

I am trying to get dataTables plugin to work with my rails application (railcast #340). I have poured over and over and have no clue where this error might be coming from. It does not look like it's any different from the code listed in http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast (except that I changed the name from Products to Users everywhere. I have completely hit a wall. My code seems to be identical in all but the name, and yet it doesn't work! (it worked before I tried to start setting up the AJAX part)

EDIT:
Originally I used 1.8.7 and rails (3.2.7), but then upgraded to ruby 1.9.3, so not sure why I am still getting that error

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: render :json => UsersDatatable.new(view_context) ?

Comment: using ruby 1.8.7 and rails (3.2.7), can the problem be coming from this? I tried using :json => but that didn't work either

Comment: What is the error you are getting now? The problem is definitely due to your ruby version.

Comment: Ok i updated the alternatives ruby path sudo update-alternatives --config ruby and selected the newest ruby, now -v gives me ruby 1.9.3p0, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ruby 1.8.7 then the syntax `json: ...` will not work.

This should work instead (as @Jérôme Boé pointed out)

```
format.json { render :json => UsersDatatable.new(view_context) }
```

Comment: I put in comment to Jerome, also I installed rvm (after the above) but the changes I make with RVM don't seem to stick when I do 'ruby -v', what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try typing: `which ruby` and see what that gives you. Probably you're running the version of ruby installed on the system. I don't use rvm (anymore) but I believe you can change the version you're using with: `rvm use 1.9.3` (or whatever version you want to use).

Comment: Anyway the question of how to get rvm to use the right version of ruby is not the one you asked here. Clearly the problem is with the ruby version. If you have issues working with rvm or installing a particular version of ruby you should post a separate question (and mark this one as the answer to this question).

Comment: I upgraded it and 'which ruby' gives me ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby, but when I run the server I still get the above error. It certainly seems that the ruby version is to blame, but i'm not sure if that's the case now

Comment: Ok first of all, assuming you're still running 1.8.7 for whatever reason, the fix (`:json =>`) should work. You say it doesn't. What is the error you get?

Comment: I think because i used the scaffolding of 1.9.3 it started complaining about those. I fixed the problem where it was running ruby 1.8.7 so it's resolved now.